# Android tab missing children after app sits

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have created an app that gets a list from a website and stores it in the cache. These values are then displayed in a tab. Each value gets put into a `TextView` that is created when the `Fragment` is created. That part works perfectly fine, even when I don't have an internet connection (so it is relying on what was stored in the cache).

I have found that if I let the app sit for a while, just using my phone as normal, when I go back into the app that tab is blank. I'm not really sure what the problem is since I don't get any error messages. If I go to the app chooser and swipe the app closed, the next time I run the app it goes back to the splash page and everything works great. Am I missing something to be able to have a view that I created programatically be able to be stored in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explicitely save the contents of your TextViews, and in general any view that you wish its contents to remain after an onPause of your activity. Specifically for TextViews you can do that in your xml definition by adding

```
android:freezesText="true"
```

If you add your TextView programmatically, you can try this:

```
textView.setFreezesText(true);
```

Comment: My XML for that tab is just a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` inside. Would I apply that to the `LinearLayout` or would I just add that to the `TextView` when I create it in the java file?

Comment: You can add it when you create it in the jave file, check my edit